# Changing field but same job as Data Analyst - red flags in new job?

Tags: career-development, hiring-process, job-change, careers

I've done an interview with a consulting company for a full remote Data Analyst PowerBi (body rental) in medical field for a big medical company.

First interview was with HR and happened yesterday.

Second interview was today with HR and commercial that handle the client.

I received the economic offer without doing a technical interview and is 50% more than my current salary with trivial accounting tricks.

There's a third interview which is technical and with the final client but they said that If I accept the economical offer, I cannot back off.

Fine for me, but it puzzles me that I still didn't understand with who I will work, which will be my team and why The hiring process is very fast.

1. I don't know with who I will work with.
2. 50% salary more but extremely above the average.
3. No technical interview and I received an offer.
4. Reviews on this company are few, both good and bad.

Should I wait for another healthcare data analyst job?

Tl:dr got offer for same job in different field, possibly red flags?

Comment: Could you add more details?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I'm in South Europe

Comment: It's not unusual to not know who you will be working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like a consulting company signed a contract with the client for lots of money but had hard time to locate sufficiently passable resource

In this case, every candidate that fits the bill for customer is ran through the stages as not to loose the client and start billing :)

Would be nice to see the offer with all the fine prints and conditions, but, IMHO, until you have a signed contract you have no obligation to this employer

Answer (score 7):

> they said that If I accept the economical offer, I cannot back off.

Thats not their call, until a contract is signed you do whatever you want.

Is it a red flag? It's certainly rushed, but there may be any number of valid reasons for that. I suggest you find out more information before making a judgement call.

Comment: Which information you would ask if I may ask?

Comment: And of course, in many situations, you can just quit during or before your first week - though it's possible there are clauses in your contract that may attach penalties for that.

Comment: Ask about whatever is stopping you. So far I don't see anything overriding. But if you have a specific issue, just ask them about it.

Answer (score 2):

I want to post how it ended :

The company that started with offering full remote, began to say 
"what if we would put 2 days of going in client site?"
I was kind of upset for this shady behavior and client location was 1 hour away from me.
Making some calculation I figured out :

- I would have had to do 1000 miles more per month
- Since they're not paying back the cost of going to client (gas, food and use of
  car)
- They wouldn't give me a company car and I would have had to use mine
- the 50% salary in advance would be hazed by the cost that this company doesn't want to pay back, so I would earn the same salary that I have now
- A friend of mine told that the location client would at least take 1h40 minutes due to traffic and that meant like 3h per week only of travelling

I also managed to meet someone who went away from this company and he confirmed what I had written above, they offer 50 % higher salaries because they don't want to pay back the transfer fees.
If I had been in my 19's, I would have accepted this contract from this shady company, but not now.

Do not get desperate about changing jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fair to ask why you have to accept the offer before talking to technical personnel. Only theory I can think of is that technical folks are in high demand and their time/focus is being managed to stay on the critical path. If you can't commit, they can't justify the time it'll take. This could be good or bad.

Did the two previous interviews challenge you? Do you feel they did due diligence of you, and subsequently everyone you'd work with? What were your questions for them...were they informative? If the whole thing felt rushed or Q&A was generic, that would be telling to me.

Comment: The first interview with HR was good and it seemed like my dream job, but it started with a body rental proposal and going to client covered in a hybrid full remote.
I wasn't totally sure, but I wanted to see what they would offer and if the offer was good, I could have accepted.

My questions were along I'm the only one data analyst ? / Do I have a mentor / How is the workflow? / Do I report directly to client? or to commercial ?  / Is it the first time for the company to invest in a Data Analyst?